# Using Dubbo in spring boot encountered "no provider available from registration"

Tags: java, apache-dubbo

This problem arises when consumers want to get the zookeeper value of the local Linux virtual machine

I used Springboot 2.1，Zookeeper is on the local Linux virtual machine. I've seen a very close answer, but I don't know how to set it up. The address is https://blog.csdn.net/chenxiaochan/article/details/78776304. What he means is that the IP of the server published by the Dubbo service uses DHCP, not static. And through his method, I queried my own ip, which is really different from the IP registered in the registry.
I've also tried to disable virtual network cards, but It means I can't connect to the local Linux virtual machine.

My provider application.properties

```
dubbo.application.name=provider-ticket
dubbo.registry.address=zookeeper://192.168.248.132:2181
dubbo.scan.base-packages=com.cq.providerticket.service
```

My consumer application.properties

```
dubbo.application.name=consumer-user
dubbo.registry.address=zookeeper://192.168.248.132:2181
dubbo.consumer.check=false
dubbo.registry.check=false
server.port=8081
dubbo.protocol.host=192.168.248.132
dubbo.provider.host=192.168.248.132
```

linux dokcer command

```
docker run --name zk01 -p 2181:2181 -p 20880:20880 --restart always -d zookeeperID
```

This is the Exception it reported.

```
Caused by: com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcException: No provider available from registry 192.168.248.132:2181 for service com.cq.consumeruser.ticket.service.TicketService on consumer 10.12.78.96 use dubbo version 2.6.5, please check status of providers(disabled, not registered or in blacklist).
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.registry.integration.RegistryDirectory.doList(RegistryDirectory.java:577)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.cluster.directory.AbstractDirectory.list(AbstractDirectory.java:74)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.cluster.support.AbstractClusterInvoker.list(AbstractClusterInvoker.java:277)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.cluster.support.AbstractClusterInvoker.invoke(AbstractClusterInvoker.java:238)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.cluster.support.wrapper.MockClusterInvoker.invoke(MockClusterInvoker.java:75)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.proxy.InvokerInvocationHandler.invoke(InvokerInvocationHandler.java:52)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.common.bytecode.proxy0.getTicket(proxy0.java)
    ... 38 more
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.getTicket(Unknown Source)
    at com.cq.consumeruser.service.UserService.buyTicket(UserService.java:17)
    at com.cq.consumeruser.ConsumerUserApplicationTests.contextLoads(ConsumerUserApplicationTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.config.spring.beans.factory.annotation.ReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ReferenceBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(ReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:159)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker in linux virtual machine, linux system is run in virutal box or VMware Workstation

1. ssh to linux
2. vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 or ifcfg-eth33 file
3. change the BOOTPROTO=dhcp to BOOTPROTO=static and set IPADDR=192.168.248.132
4. make sure 20880 and 2181 port is open through firewall

If you use docker for windows,linux virtual is in hyper-v, 192.168.248.132 is your windows computer ip

1. set the dubbo.registry.address=zookeeper://localhost:2181
2. set the dubbo.protocol.host=localhost and dubbo.provider.host=localhost

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still makes the same mistake.